# Non-rotational movement about an axis?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, terminology

So we know the rotational movements about the 3 axes are called roll pitch and yaw. But what are the non-rotational movements called? For example a jackhammer - the bit is moving along the longitudinal axis, but not rotating. What is that back and forth movement called?

Comment: We don't usually talk about linear motions _about_ an axis. We normally would say,  "along" the axis, or "parallel to" the axis, or something like.

Answer (score 0):

The translational analogues for roll (rotational movement about the X axis), pitch (rotational movement about the Y axis), and yaw (rotational movement about the Z axis) are surge (back and forth movement along the X axis), sway (side to side movement along the Y axis), and heave (up and down movement along the Z axis).

An airplane yaws, a jackhammer heaves.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_freedom